# How to write dot automatically after reference to images and equations?

Tags: cross-referencing

When I use `\ref{fig:sth}`, LaTeX writes the number of the figure into the text. How do I make LaTeX automatically write a dot after the number of the figure/table/equation/etc.?

Comment: do you really want a dot if the reference is not at the end of a sentence?  (i think this would be confusing.)

Comment: Do you also have a dot after the figure number with the caption? As in `Figure 1. This is a figure.`?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I do. It's because according to the grammatical rules of the language I speak I should write it like "1. ábra" ("ábra" means "Figure" in English).

Comment: @user3237992: Then it may suffice to add `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}` to your preamble. This assumes that your figures are numbered on their own (no chapter/section prefix).

Comment: @Werner Thank you. I'd give you a vote, but I don't have the privilige to do that.

Comment: @user3237992: I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an ending period with *all* appearances to a figure (both in the setting and the cross-referencing), you can change the representation

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
```

Similarly, for tables, you can add

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}.}
```

to your preamble. For equations, one can do the same, of course, redefining

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}.}
```

The above redefinitions assume that figures (and tables, equations) are not numbered within any other constructs (like sections).